# Unblocking UI Thread while avoiding NetworkOnMainThread Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, android-studio

I have a function where I have to get code from server and return its operation.

Here is the code

```
public String getResult
{
        // Call to your backend

        try {
            String url = String.format(Constants.LOGIN_URL,
                    URLEncoder.encode(countryCode + phoneNumber, "UTF-8"),
                    URLEncoder.encode(smsCode, "UTF-8"),
                    URLEncoder.encode(Constants.WHERE_API_KEY, "UTF-8"));

            while (new LoginToServer().execute(url).get());

        }catch (Exception e)
        {}

return result; // Result will be saved to class in onPostExecute()
```

My `LoginToServer` returns true if there was an error retrieving the result. Now, This will most obviously remove the Exception of `NetworkOnMainThread`, however it iwll block UI.

since the function is to be called by some sdks , it is imperative that i make `httpconnection` so that it completes then pass on the result.

How can I make UI To unblock while executing this code ?

Again i can't call entire function as aysnc because the function is to be called by most sdk functions internally and they will diffidently not call it in Async

Comment: This is NOT what i want. i want to return until the operation is complete like synchronous

Comment: defeating the definition of asynchronous, which is what you need, how about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use something like an `AsyncTask`. Of course you can abstract this way from users of your SDK/library so that they call simply call a `doLogin()` function, and into that function they pass a callback interface that will be called when the login result returns.

```
public void doLogin(final MyCallback callback) {

    new AsyncTask<URL, Void, Boolean> {
        protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            // make network calls to login in this "background" thread.
            loginSuccess = true;
            return loginSuccess;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean loginSuccess) {
           callback.onResult(loginSuccess);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Notice how this `doLogin` method returns immediately, and will call the `callback` only after the network call has completed (perhaps many seconds later). This is how you do non-blocking work, and keep the main thread and app UI responsive.

Comment: This is interesting i didn't think of that :) let me try

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make UI To unblock while executing this code ?

Get rid of `get()` and process the results of the URL in `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`.

Or, replace `AsyncTask` with a regular thread, and call `getResult()` on a background thread, with appropriate synchronization logic between them. This would be wasteful, as you should not need two threads here, but it gets the main application thread out of the mix.

You simply cannot call `getResult()` on the main application thread, for a blocking call, and have that blocking call somehow not block.

Comment: Theoretically it is possible to write a blocking method which runs on the UI thread without blocking it: the method must internally run the event loop, polling the completion status of the HTTP request on each iteration. This a regular pattern in SWT; but on Android it doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes i can call getResult on background threads but the libs i am using DO NOT. so i need to get a workaround

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: Unless the library is providing you with the application components (e.g., activities), I fail to see how the library is controlling what thread is used. But, assuming that you are correct, and the library is forcing the main application thread, you either have to stop using those libraries or stop trying to do network I/O directly in response to a callback from the library.

Answer (score 0):

Async threads are used for time consuming operations (Network might be slow/server might be slow/ many hops between client server etc.)

To not block the UI thread functioning, while data is being fetched from server, is what async calls are used for.

You can call this function from Asyctasks doInBackground() method.

the UI thread will function normally  and process result in PostExecute() callback.

What is the challenge you are facing? surely several functions can call it in async. Do you want to synchronize the Async calls? You can use [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) for that.

Look into Native Android async Class or libraries like LoopJ